# multiple sorts on list<Of T>

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, generics, sorting

I am using VB.NET and .NET framework 3.0

I am currently sorting a list like this:

```
  lstPeople.Sort(Function(p1, p2) p1.LName.CompareTo(p2.LName))
```

However, now I want to sort by FName as well after the LName. So it sorts first by last name and then by first name.

Is this possible?

Comment: You'll have to implement your own `IComparer` if you can't use Linq

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Yes, just write a comparer that implements the ordering that you want. So compare the last name first; if they are not equal return the result of `CompareTo` and if they are not equal return the comparison between the first names.

Comment: Will it work under .NET 3.0? I remember trying to implement something like this a while back, but I was unable to do so. Using IComparer right?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible.
I think the best way, if you can change the "People" class, create you own `CompareTo()` function.

```
Private Function CompareTo(p2 As People) As Integer
    Dim i As Int32 = Me.LName.CompareTo(p2.LName)
    If i = 0 Then
        Return Me.FName.CompareTo(p2.FName)
    End If
    Return i
End Function
```

then use it :

```
  lstPeople.Sort(Function(p1, p2) p1.CompareTo(p2))
```

EDIT : Convert to VB.NET.

Comment: thanks, and what if I wanted to do many more sorts i.e. sort by A, then by B, then by C and then by D

Comment: CompareTo return 0 when the 2 object are identical. So if the last CompareTo return 0, go to you next criteria.. and continue until you found some difference..

Comment: Any chance of a VB.NET version?

Comment: I changed to VB.NET. BTW, you can look on the internet you will find many converter from C# to VB.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Public Class PeopleComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of People)

    Public Function Compare(x As People, y As People) As Integer
         Dim lnameComparison As Integer = x.LName.CompareTo(y.LName)
         Return If(lnameComparison = 0, x.FName.CompareTo(y.FName), lnameComparison)
    End Function
End Class
```

and

```
lstPeople.Sort(New PeopleComparer())
```

Comment: You should be able to use IComparer(of T) in 3.0

Comment: cool.. thanks. I was referring to 3.0 for your initial post :)... btw, if I wanted to do multiple sorts how can I do this? i.e. Sort of A then by B, then by C and then by D?

Comment: Put the sort logic, however you want it, in Compare Function. This function returns integer.Less than zero
x is less than y.
Zero
x equals y.
Greater than zero
x is greater than y.

Comment: I get an error such that PeopleComparer must implement "Function Compare(x As People, y As People) As Integer" for interface IComparer(of People)?

Comment: In the above example, there  is a function with that signature. Did you use the PeopleComparer as shown above?

Comment: I used this:
Public Class ItemComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of SB)

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As SB, ByVal y As SB) As Integer
        Dim iComparison As Integer = x.Item.CompareTo(y.Item)
        Return If(iComparison = 0, x.We.CompareTo(y.We), iComparison)
    End Function
End Class

Comment: In your ItemComparer, x.Item and x.We should be string or a basic value type such as int, long, double, etc. If not it should be be a type that implements IComparer.

Comment: and I tried doing x.We.toString().CompareTo(y.We.toString()), yet I get the same error

Comment: See tweak to this answer below. (Can't put code in a comment.)

Answer (score 0):

`Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of People).Compare` have to be added to the function. Stub is generated by typing enter key after `IComparer(Of People)`

```
Public Class PeopleComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of People)

    Public Function Compare(x As People, y As People) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of People).Compare
        Dim lnameComparison As Integer = x.LName.CompareTo(y.LName)
        Return If(lnameComparison = 0, x.FName.CompareTo(y.FName), lnameComparison)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Bala R's answer is essentially correct, but I had to provide the compiler with a little more information to get past the compiler error you were seeing:

```
Public Class PeopleComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of People)

    Public Function Compare(x As People, y As People) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of People).Compare
         Dim lnameComparison As Integer = x.LName.CompareTo(y.LName)
         Return If(lnameComparison = 0, x.FName.CompareTo(y.FName), lnameComparison)
    End Function
End Class
```

and

```
lstPeople.Sort(New PeopleComparer())
```